# Help installing DB-main

Tags: software-installation, sql

I want to install a program called DB-main and have the same problem as [this person](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1948507). I have extracted the file and the instructions which say:

> Edit the `.bashrc` file (`.profile` in some environments) in the home directory and add the following lines (adapt the ~/db-main/bin directory to the one chosen previously):

```
export DB_MAIN_BIN=~/db-main/bin
export PATH=$DB_MAIN_BIN:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DB_MAIN_BIN:$DB_MAIN_BIN/../java/jre/lib/i386/client:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
CLASSPATH modification only for dbm-deasy-9xx-linux-setup.tar.gz
export CLASSPATH=.:$DB_MAIN_BIN/../plugins/deasy/lib/jidbmjava.jar:$DB_MAIN_BIN/../plugins/deasy/lib/sqlite-jdbc-3.6.20.1.jar:$CLASSPATH
```

What is this? I don't know what "home directory" is but there is no `.bashrc` or `.profile` file either in `/home/erik` or `/home`, nor in any of the (many!) subdirectories of `db-main`.

Comment: They are there in `/home/erik` but you don't see them in Nautilus because of these two dotfiles are hidden. Press Ctrl+H to show hidden files and you will see them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you add those lines to `.profile` which is more appropriate for setting environment variables

@edwinksl is totally right, the files are there, just hidden, because their names start with  a dot `.`

In a terminal, you can first make a copy of the file you are going to edit, and then open it with a text editor

```
cp .profile profile-bak
gedit .profile
```

then scroll down to the end of the file and paste all the lines there. Save and exit, then log out and log back in for the changes to your environment to be loaded.

Comment: It's a pleasure :D @ErikVesterlund